# Incorrect number of arguments for procedure (mysql) expected and got does not match

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli, error-handling

I have a `procedure` with 22 arguments with `IN` direction, and one argument called `p_return` is `OUT` direction. So my input must have 22 arguments.

But this error occur: ( I use codeigniter framework )

> **Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE royalshoe.Set_Shoe_SP; expected 23, got 22**

mysqli:

```
$query = $this->db->query("call Set_Shoe_SP(1, NULL , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
                                , array((int)$first_type, (int)$second_type, (int)$brand, (int)$khord, (int)$bonak, (int)$omdeh, (int)$chahar, (int)$degree, (int)$tarikh, $file_coma, (int)$bestseller, (int)$loverproduct, 1 , $content, $full_model, $relation, $file_coma, $size_coma, $color_coma, $number_coma));
```

In `procedure` , When I execute with 22 inputs it works correctly.

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: where is your query? please post it.

Comment: @RonakPatel You can check now, Thanks a lot.